# Question Regarding Bond-Coupon Prices with Partial Period Maturity Date

Tags: bonds, bond-coupons

Question:

What would you pay for the following bonds assuming an annual yield rate of 7% based on semi-annual compounding (assume face value = $100)? A bond with a coupon rate of 6% maturing in **3 years and 3 months** from now?

Would I approach this as I would normally but with 6.5 periods?

P = 3 * [1-(1/(1+0.035)^6.5 )]/0.035 + 100/(1+0.035)^6.5

Would this be correct?